# How to make an INNER JOIN in my model using cakePHP?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

My model is 'Apertura' and has many 'AperturaArticulo' but when I call this I get the next fields from AperturaArticulo:
**id | price | total | created | modified | articulo_id**

I want to change **articulo_id** by **Articulo.description** so I need an INNER JOIN but I don't know how to do it.

Here is my code:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'AperturaArticulo' => array(
        'className' => 'AperturaArticulo',
        'foreignKey' => 'apertura_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )       
);
```

I hope you can help me!

---

UPDATE:
1) I have a view where I call 'AperturaArticulo' from my model called 'Apertura' and I have the next table: [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VP9b0.png) . All that using the next code in my view:

```
<?php if (!empty($apertura['AperturaArticulo'])): ?>
<table cellpadding = "0" cellspacing = "0">
<tr>
    <th><?php echo __('Articulo'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo __('Cantidad'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo __('Precio'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo __('Total'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo __('Fecha de alta'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo __('Última modificación'); ?></th>
    <th class="actions"><?php echo __('Acciones'); ?></th>
</tr>
<?php foreach ($apertura['AperturaArticulo'] as $aperturaArticulo): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $aperturaArticulo['articulo_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $aperturaArticulo['cantidad']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $aperturaArticulo['precio']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $aperturaArticulo['total']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $aperturaArticulo['created']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $aperturaArticulo['modified']; ?></td>
        <td class="actions">
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('View'), array('controller' => 'apertura_articulos', 'action' => 'view', $aperturaArticulo['id'])); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), array('controller' => 'apertura_articulos', 'action' => 'edit', $aperturaArticulo['id'])); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), array('controller' => 'apertura_articulos', 'action' => 'delete', $aperturaArticulo['id']), array(), __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $aperturaArticulo['id'])); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

In the first line you can see $apertura[AperturaArticulo]. $apertura is my model and [AperturaArticulo] is the relation hasMany in my model.

2) If you see in the table show the first column with numbers. Those numbers are the field 'articulo_id' of a table called 'AperturaArticulo'.

3) The associations are:

'apertura_id' is the foreign key so in the table just show the 'AperturaArticulos' where apertura_id = n

In my DB I have 3 tables.

'aperturas' -> **id | vendedore_id | vehiculo_id | observaciones | created | modified**

'apertura_articulos' -> **id | tipo | apertura_id | articulo_id | cantidad | precio | total | created | modified**

'articulos' -> **id | codigo_articulo | descripcion | unidad | precio | activo | articulo_grupo | marca | existencia | proveedor_id | created | modified**

In my model 'Apertura' I have a relation hasMany where one **Apertura** has many **AperturaArticulos**.

But all that I want is in the hasMany apply an inner join between apertura_articulos and articulos. That's it. Thank u!

Comment: What do you mean by the following: 1) "but when I call this" - what are you actually doing? 2) "I want to change articulo_id by Articulo.description" - what do you mean by "change"? 3) What is articulo_id? - in your code, you have apertura_id. Can you provide the association for your AperturaArticulo model as well?

Comment: I have updated the information. I hope it useful.